# Why do my custom fonts work from Eclipse, but not from an exported JAR?

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, jar

I am trying to hack together a game in Java, and on the start screen I used a custom font I downloaded. When I run the program from Eclipse, the screen looks like this (just as it should):
[image: Lovely font.]

However, when I run the program from the compiled jar, the screen looks like this:
[image: Whut]

Here is my code for loading the font:

```
title = new JLabel("philip k. dick"); // font requires all lowercase
try {
    Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(Util.getFile("all used up.ttf")));
    title.setFont(new Font(f.getName(), f.getStyle(), 150));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Font oldFont = title.getFont();
    title.setFont(new Font(oldFont.getName(), oldFont.getStyle(), 100));
}
```

The method `Util.getFile` just adds "resources/" to the beginning of the given `String`.

There are no errors given when I run the jar from the command line. I know that the program can access the font resource because when I rename the "resources" folder (to prevent access), the screen looks like this:
[image: As expected.]

Additionally, I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Can't read resources/all used up.ttf
```

Of course, THIS is expected.

I would also like to note that I have other audio and image resources being loaded from the same location, and they work fine. This location is in the folder directly outside of the jar. Also, I am using a Mac, but I get the same problem on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of your `resources` directly are typically add to your Jar.

This means that they can no longer be access using a `File` object, as they are actually now part of a Zip file.

You need to use something like `getClass().getResource(...)` to it up.  This returns an instance of `URL` which points to the resource (if it can be found)

However, `Font.createFont` takes either a `File` or `InputStream` reference, in this case you should use `getClass().getResourceAsInputStream(...)`, something like...

```
Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsInputStream("resources/all used up.ttf"));
```

This makes a "relative" path request from the context of the class trying to load the resource.  This is probably not going to work, so instead, you could use

```
getClass().getResourceAsInputStream("/resources/all used up.ttf")
```

Which creates an absolute path lookup from the context of the classpath

If you get stuck, try unpacking the Jar and see if the font resides within and where and make adjusts as required.

**Updated...**

Try using...

```
Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("resources/all used up.ttf"));
title.setFont(f.deriveFont(150f));
```

As I understand it, `new Font(...)` is trying to find the font from the available system fonts.

From the [Java Docs for `Font#createFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29)...

> This base font can then be used with the deriveFont methods in this
>   class to derive new Font objects with varying sizes, styles,
>   transforms and font features. ...
> To make the `Font` available to `Font`
>   constructors the
>   returned `Font` must be registered in the `GraphicsEnviroment` by calling
>   `registerFont(Font)`.

Comment: I have the font in a folder called "resources" that sits in the same folder as the jar. I have other information (images and audio) that are drawn from this same folder that work fine. I understand that the method you described is the better way, but I was not aware of this until my program was almost finished. I do not want to rework everything now. Shouldn't I be able to load the fonts from the same place I load everything else? Why is it that just the fonts don't work?

Comment: After using the information from your updates, the problem was solved. Thanks!